# regular expression for finding this pattern :

Tags: regex

```
new line integer | string | integer ||
```

Note the double vertical bar at end, a single vertical-bar is being used a delimiter.

For example the bold below would be found :

> *11|Any String and numbers|939|ANY STRING|anything including delimter |*
>
> ***138151|Any String and numbers|90139||anything including delimter |***
>
> *13811|Any String and numbers9|885|Morestring|anything including delimter |*

I looking for the row the where the field between 3rd and 4th delimter is empty.

Comment: The `|` character is called "pipe"

Comment: @Bohemian is it ? I thought that was the actual action performed in unix, not the name of the symbol ?

Comment: That's what people call it - "a pipe character". Wiki says [Vertical Bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar), with "pipe" being a common name for it, due (as you say) to it meaning in unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
^\d+\|[^|]+\|\d+\|\|
```

Breaking this down:

- `^` means "start of line"
- `\d+` means "at least one digit"
- `\|` means "a literal vertical bar character" (need to escape it because on its own it means "logical or")
- `[^|]+` means "at least one non-vertical bar character". Note that you *don't* need to escape characters within a character class `[...]` (except of course the closing bracket `]`).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on language/regex flavor you could use an expression like:

```
(?mx) ^ \d+ \| [^|]+ \| \d+ \|\| .*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[0-9]+\|[ a-zA-Z0-9_]+\|[0-9]+\|.*\|$
```

You need to tweak what is 'text' for you and make groups to extract. You can test it here: http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 1):

For single line:

```
\d+\|[^|]+\|\d+\|\|.*
```

For multiple lines:

```
^\d+\|[^|]+\|\d+\|\|.*$
```